# How to change View area on click without setState in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

I have an app like this:

[image]

At the moment it is built with expo and MapView. When you click an address it animates to the pin using this animateToRegion function:

```
<MapView>
....
</MapView>
<ScrollView style={ styles.mapStyle }>
    {waypoint.map((item, i) => {
        return (
            <View key={i}>
                <View style={styles.houseList}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.addressButtons}
                        onPress = {() => this.mapView.animateToRegion({
                            latitude: item.latitude,
                            longitude: item.longitude
                        }, 1000)}>
                        <Text>{item.address}</Text>
                     </TouchableOpacity>
                 </View>
               </View>
          );
     })}
</ScrollView>
```

What I want to do is keep this animation but also change what is shown in the "ScrollView" component.
I have tried the `{ifImTrue && <ScrollView.....</ScrollView>}` with an alternate for `!ifImTrue` but because I am trying to use `setState` it stops my animation (because it refreshes?). How can i make ScrollView's content change on Press of the `TouchableOpacity` button and keep my animation running?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try adding the selected item from your waypoint array (assign a unique id to identify every object) in the state and do a 
```selectedWayPoint === 'some value'? <SomeModifiedView/>: <DefaultView/>``` inside your map?

Comment: Would it work to just set the state on click and use useEffect to animate to the region?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options that I have in mind right now:

1. Run your animation after calling `setState()`:

```
this.setState({
    yourContent: yourValue
}, () => {
    // Your animation called here
})
```

2. Rewrite your item components in `<ScrollView>`. Basically, you want your items to re-render (refresh as you said before) by itself. To achieve that, you can try these steps:

   - Store your item's value in a variable, not in `state` in order that you can update without re-rendering `Parent` component.
   - Override `shouldComponentUpdate()` in your item's class. You can read more in this link: [React Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate). For example, you can re-render your item's component ONLY by trying this (assuming that your `data` will be passed through `this.props.data`):

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return this.props.data !=== nextProps.data;
}
```

After this, when you change your item's value in `Parent` component, your item component will check its current data with new data it received, and re-render if they're different.

### Note

You'd better read the link I mentioned above carefully before overriding this method. The reason is:

> Use `shouldComponentUpdate()` to let React know if a component’s output is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior.
>
> `shouldComponentUpdate()` is invoked before rendering when new props or state are being received. Defaults to true. This method is not called for the initial render or when `forceUpdate()` is used.

For short, this function will be called when your `state` and `props` changed, when you update your `props` from outside or call `setState()` from inside. Since my example only check `nextProps`, the `nextState` will be ignore and this will make your `setState()` function WITHIN your item component will run unexpectedly (still run but has no change in visual because there is no re-render)